# Display Image as Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, uint8array

I know that this question has already some responses but one of them is very clear.

I have the following array:

```
Uint8Array[112, 135, 57, 112, 135, 56, 109, 133, 58, 109, 131, 55, 108, 130, 53, 106, 127, 54, 102, 123, 51, 102, 122, 54, 103, 121, 55, 102, 121, 53, 100, 119, 53, ...]
```

with 19000 elements (it is a rgb image flatten from numpy)

I have a react app that has:

The question is now how can I fill this image without converting it to base64.
I tried a lot of things like:

```
const data = new Uint8Array(image[0].image);
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/png" });
const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

setting imageUrl into src= does not work, I was looking at the image-js library but I need some help

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this on the backend:

```
image = Image.fromarray(img_uint8)
img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
image.save(img_byte_arr, format='JPEG')
img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
b64_str_img = base64.b64encode(img_byte_arr).decode()
```

On the frontend I did:

```
<img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64,".concat(`b64_str_img`)} width="512px"></img>
```